# AWS postgres copying data from one database to the other daily?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to create an automated job that can copy the entire database to a different one, both are in AWS RDS Postgres, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you going to overwrite the _whole_ database? If so, creating a new one from a snapshot is the easiest. If you do _not_ want to overwrite the whole database, please edit your question to add the relevant details. Please include what you would like to happen to the existing tables (delete them?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had success in the past running a script that dumps data from one Postgres server and pipes it into another server. It was basically like this **pseudo-code**:

```sh
psql target-database -c "truncate foo"
pg_dump source-database --data-only --table=foo | psql target-database
```

The `pg_dump` command outputs normal SQL commands that can be piped into a receiving `psql` command, which then inserts the data.

To understand how this works, run `pg_dump` on one table and then take a look at the output. You'll need to tweak the command to get exactly what you want (eg using `--no-owner` to avoid sending access configurations).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Database [create](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html)/[restore snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html).

Here is the example for command line:

```
aws rds create-db-snapshot \
    --db-instance-identifier mydbinstance \
    --db-snapshot-identifier mydbsnapshot 

aws rds restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot \
    --db-instance-identifier mynewdbinstance \
    --db-snapshot-identifier mydbsnapshot
```

The same APIs such as [CreateDBSnapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBSnapshot.html) are available for multiple languages via AWS SDK.

Comment: Not sure I explained properly, the target DB is an existing one that I need to be overwritten with production data, so creating a new DB is not an option (connection settings etc.)

Comment: From the restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot docs: If your intent is to replace your original DB instance  with  the  new,  restored  DB instance, then rename your original DB instance before you call the RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot action ... The result  is  that  you  will   replace  the original DB instance with the DB instance created from the snapshot.